# How can I get rid of unsampled data in an R heatmap after sampling?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

The following code produces a heatmap but shows labels on the y axis for all 194 countries included in the original dataset (before sampling).  This continues to happen even if I remove the original dataset.  I've also tried shutting down the console to start a new session, to no avail.

```
qlife.s <- myData[sample(194,size=10,replace=F),]

qlife.s.m <- melt(qlife.s)

qlife.s.m <- ddply(qlife.s.m, .(variable), transform, rescale=rescale(value))

(p <- ggplot(qlife.s.m, aes(variable, qlife.s.m$Country))
      + geom_tile( aes(fill = rescale),
                   colour = "white")
      + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")
)
```

Any advice is much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `?droplevels` seems like a good idea.

Comment: This has been discussed many times on this site, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1195826/429846 or see several other questions all using the `droplevels()` function http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+droplevels

Comment: Does this qualify for an `r-faq` tag?

Answer (score 4):

Use `droplevels()` on your data. By the looks of things:

```
qlife.s.m <- droplevels(qlife.s.m)
```

should do what you want, but it is difficult to tell without a reproducible example.