# Ghost factor levels in R

Tags: r, subset, r-factor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dropping factor levels in a subsetted data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/dropping-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame-in-r)

I have subsetted away observations with a certain factor level. When checking whether this has been done with `summary()` the levels were still listed, but with zero observations. Shouldn't they disappear during the subsetting?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Subsetting doesn't drop empty levels. Why this is the case is that it is a feature. Think of it as your factor levels determine the possible/potential categories of a **thing**. If you only take a subset of these things, the possible categories of **thing** don't change, your subset just doesn't contain any of them.

If you want to drop these empty levels, see `?droplevels`.

Comment: The only danger of `droplevels` applied to a data frame is that by default it will drop empty levels for **all** factors (rather than just for levels of the focal factor), which might be undesired.

Comment: Right, for the single factor I'd do `obj <- transform(obj, fac = droplevels(fac))` if I wanted to leave other factors untouched.

Answer (score 9):

To make the extra levels disappear, use `drop=TRUE` when subsetting:

```
newfactor <- oldfactor[indices, drop=TRUE]
```

Incidentally, one reason this is not the default is that factors with different levels cannot be compared. So if you want to compare your factors with the original vector, or perhaps a different subset of the vector, you'd need to keep the extra levels.