# r random forest error - type of predictors in new data do not match

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to use quantile regression forest function in R ([quantregForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantregForest/quantregForest.pdf)) which is built on Random Forest package. I am getting a type mismatch error that I can't quite figure why.

I train the model by using

```
qrf <- quantregForest(x = xtrain, y = ytrain)
```

which works without a problem, but when I try to test with new data like

```
quant.newdata <- predict(qrf, newdata= xtest)
```

it gives the following error:

```
Error in predict.quantregForest(qrf, newdata = xtest) : 
Type of predictors in new data do not match types of the training data.
```

My training and testing data are coming from separate files (hence separate data frames) but having the same format. I have checked the classes of the predictors with

```
sapply(xtrain, class)
sapply(xtest, class)
```

Here is the output:

```
> sapply(xtrain, class)
pred1     pred2     pred3     pred4     pred5     pred6     pred7     pred8 
"factor" "integer" "integer" "integer"  "factor"  "factor" "integer"  "factor" 
pred9    pred10    pred11    pred12 
"factor"  "factor"  "factor"  "factor" 


> sapply(xtest, class)
pred1     pred2     pred3     pred4     pred5     pred6     pred7     pred8 
"factor" "integer" "integer" "integer"  "factor"  "factor" "integer"  "factor" 
pred9    pred10    pred11    pred12 
"factor"  "factor"  "factor"  "factor"
```

They are exactly the same. I also checked for the "NA" values. Neither xtrain nor xtest has a NA value in it. Am I missing something trivial here?

Update I: running the prediction on the training data still gives the same error

```
> quant.newdata <- predict(qrf, newdata = xtrain)
Error in predict.quantregForest(qrf, newdata = xtrain) : 
names of predictor variables do not match
```

Update II: I combined my training and test sets so that rows from 1 to 101 are the training data and the rest is the testing. I modified the example provided in ([quantregForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantregForest/quantregForest.pdf)) as:

```
data <-  read.table("toy.txt", header = T)
n <- nrow(data)
indextrain <- 1:101
xtrain <- data[indextrain, 3:14]
xtest <- data[-indextrain, 3:14]
ytrain <- data[indextrain, 15]
ytest <- data[-indextrain, 15]

qrf <- quantregForest(x=xtrain, y=ytrain)
quant.newdata <- predict(qrf, newdata= xtest)
```

And it works! I'd appreciate if any one could explain why it works this way and not with the other way?

Comment: Having two `pred1` values that have different types doesn't seem like a great idea. Maybe change the factor one to be called `pred1.factor'?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I changed it and reran the sapply's. Still getting the same error both with new data = xtrain and new data = xtest

Comment: What happens if you start from a small number of predictors, and add them one at a time?

Comment: When I made predictions using `quantregForest` and an entirely separate testing dataset, I was only using some of the variables in the new dataset.  I subset to the variables of interest with `newdata = allsites2[,names(modqr$forest$ncat)]`, where `modqr` was the quantregForest object and `allsites2` was the testing dataset.  You might check if this works for you (or at least helps you troubleshoot a bit).

Comment: Do you know if your factors in both sets contain the same levels? i.e. if you have T / F in your training data, does the corresponding column in your testing data also have both T and F?

Comment: @Karan the levels of the factors are different for at least one of the predictors. Why would it be a problem for separate training - test data but not for the a single data set partitioned into training and test?

Comment: This is just an idea - a single data set partitioned into training and test will still have the same factor levels since the presence of all factor types (T, F) causes all levels to be present in that column. On second thought, however, you got an error when testing the original training set as well, which is worrisome. A quick way to see if this idea holds any merit is to reduce your data set, modify the data so that all levels are the same, and see if anything works. Just a thought - if I find any precedence for this, I'll add to the comment.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055076/r-randomforest-subsetting-cant-get-rid-of-factor-levels

Answer (score 41):

I had the same problem. You can try to use small trick to equalize classes of training and test set. Bind the first row of training set to the test set and than delete it. For your example it should look like this:

```
    xtest <- rbind(xtrain[1, ] , xtest)
    xtest <- xtest[-1,]
```

Comment: This really does fix it, I tried all kinds of weird ass complicated loops/applies/checking and this just fixes it gg

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The right answer! Credits!

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for this brilliant solution!

Comment: This is great. Its also possible that you could have ended up with a factor in your test that isn't in your training data, so you can use: test <- rbind(train[1, ] , test)
test <- test[-1,]
train <- rbind(test[1, ] , train)
train <- train[-1,]

Answer (score 16):

@mgoldwasser is right in general, but there is also a very nasty bug in `predict.randomForest`: Even if you have exactly the same levels in the training and in the prediction set, it is possible to get this error. This is possible when you have a factor where you have embedded `NA` as a separate level. The problem is that `predict.randomForest` essentially does the following:

```
# Assume your original factor has two "proper" levels + NA level:
f <- factor(c(0,1,NA), exclude=NULL)

length(levels(f)) # => 3
levels(f)         # => "0" "1" NA

# Note that
sum(is.na(f))     # => 0
# i.e., the values of the factor are not `NA` only the corresponding level is.

# Internally predict.randomForest passes the factor (the one of the training set)
# through the function `factor(.)`.
# Unfortunately, it does _not_ do this for the prediction set.
# See what happens to f if we do that:
pf <- factor(f)

length(levels(pf)) # => 2
levels(pf)         # => "0" "1"

# In other words:
length(levels(f)) != length(levels(factor(f))) 
# => sad but TRUE
```

So, it will always discard the `NA` level from the training set and will always see one additional level in the prediction set.

A workaround is to replace the value `NA` of the level before using randomForest:

```
levels(f)[is.na(levels(f))] <- "NA"
levels(f) # => "0"  "1"  "NA"
          #              .... note that this is no longer a plain `NA`
```

Now calling `factor(f)` won't discard the level, and the check succeeds.

Comment: I had this issue after i had run a forest for 3 or so days ... i really didn't want to run it again :/ this seemed to fix it:
`rf$forest$xlevels$my_factor_name[myNAlevelIdx] <- "NA"`

Comment: If you're operating in the tidyverse, `forcats::fct_explicit_na` is a nice solution to this annoying bug.

Answer (score 16):

This happens because your factor variables in training set and test set have different levels(to be more precise test set doesn't have some of the levels present in training). So you can solve this for example by using below code for all your factor variables.:

```
levels(test$SectionName) <- levels(train$SectionName)
```

Comment: To expand on the solution:

`common <- intersect(names(train), names(test))`
    for (p in common) {
      if (class(train[[p]]) == "factor") {
        levels(test[[p]]) <- levels(train[[p]])
      }
    }

Comment: @JamesHirschorn Terrific!

Comment: I am trying your suggestion:
levels(test$SectionName) <- levels(train$SectionName)
on my code with 342k rows in train and 32k rows in test, but my RStudio (32bit) hasn't reacted in over half an hour. How do I know whether it's working or not? Don't want to terminate RStudio (again).

Comment: @JamesHirschorn, I suggest to add your comment as a answer, so people like me could find it easier. It solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: @Eduaro Good idea :) Done!

Answer (score 15):

Expanding on @user1849895's solution:

```
common <- intersect(names(train), names(test)) 
for (p in common) { 
  if (class(train[[p]]) == "factor") { 
    levels(test[[p]]) <- levels(train[[p]]) 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the levels of each of the different factors. You need to check to make sure that your factor levels stay consistent between your test and training sets.

This is a weird quirk of random forest, and it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved doing the following:

```
## Creating sample data
values_development=factor(c("a", "b", "c")) ## Values used when building the random forest model
values_production=factor(c("a", "b", "c", "ooops")) ## New values to used when using the model

## Deleting cases which were not present when developing
values_production=sapply(as.character(values_production), function(x) if(x %in% values_development) x else NA)

## Creating the factor variable, (with the correct NA value level)
values_production=factor(values_production)

## Checking
values_production # =>  a     b     c  <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to use this way to solved and it works.

**get the factor level from the rf model itself directly**

```
levels(PredictData$columnName) <- rfmodels$forest$xlevels$columnName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
levels(PredictData$columnName) <- rfmodels$forest$xlevels$columnName
```

However, this will change the original data in PredictData. Hence following code has to be there

```
x<-PredictData
levels(PredictData$columnName) <- rfmodels$forest$xlevels$columnName

for (i in 1:length(x$columnName))
{
  PredictData$columnName[i] <- x$columnName[i]
}
```

The above piece of code will solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same bug, in my case it was caused by tidyverse. data.frame was set to tibble and it did not match factors somehow. applying as.data.frame() did the job.