# Warning: Error in predict.randomForest: Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data

Tags: r, shiny, random-forest, prediction

I get the above error message when trying to predict for a single new instance in Shiny, hence there cannot be a problem with the test data having a different number of levels.

```
RF<-randomForest(incurred_loss2~turnover+Limite.PI+NUTS1,data=sec,importance=TRUE,ntree=2000)

modelPred<-reactive({
  turnoverInput<-as.numeric(input$sliderTurnover)
  LOIInput<-as.numeric(input$sliderLOI)
  LegalInput<-as.factor(input$selectLegal)
  NUTS1Input<-as.factor(input$selectNUTS1)
  predict(RF,newdata=data.frame(legal_form=LegalInput,turnover=turnoverInput,Limite.PI=LOIInput,NUTS1=NUTS1Input))
})
```

When I drop the two factor variables from the model so that I am only left with the two numerical variables I do not get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the data structure used to train the "RF" model isn't the same as the test data structure, and the fact that dropping the factors variables makes your code work confirms you have an issue with factors that aren't identical.

Seeing your code it might be possible as your training and testing sets aren't subsetted from the same/unique data.frame, and as you do several manual conversions (including manual conversions on factors).

I'd see two things to try depending on what you need:

- merging your sets into one data.frame with a key column you can use
  to separate train and test
- or creating a function which outputs a standardized dataset you can use in your task, and passing your test and train set inside this
  function (setting NA as an explicit level)

Below an example of problems manual conversions could cause using factors in random forests if one of your datasets have NA and the other has not:

[r random forest error - type of predictors in new data do not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829674/r-random-forest-error-type-of-predictors-in-new-data-do-not-match)