# Single input data.frame instead of testset.csv fails in randomForest code in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I have written a R script which successfully runs and predicts output but only when csv with multiple entries is passed as input to classifier.

```
training_set = read.csv('finaldata.csv')
library(randomForest)
set.seed(123)
classifier = randomForest(x = training_set[-5],
                      y = training_set$Song,
                      ntree = 50)

test_set = read.csv('testSet.csv')
y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test_set)
```

Above code runs succesfully, but instead of giving 10+ inputs to classifier, I want to pass a data.frame as single input to this classifier. That works in other classifier except this, why?
So following code doesn't work and throws error -

```
y_pred = predict(classifier, data.frame(Emot="happy",Pact="Walking",Mact="nothing",Session="morning"))
```

`Error in predict.randomForest(classifier, data.frame(Emot = "happy",  : 
  Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.`

**I even tried keeping single entry in testinput.csv**, still throws same error! How to solve it? This code is back-end of my another code and I want only single entry to pass as test to predict results. Also all are 'factors' in training as well as testing set. Help appreciated.

**PS:** Previous solutions to same error, didn't help me.

str(test_set)

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Emot   : Factor w/ 1 level "fear": 1
 $ Pact   : Factor w/ 1 level "Bicycling": 1
 $ Mact   : Factor w/ 1 level "browsing": 1
 $ Session: Factor w/ 1 level "morning": 1
 $ Song   : Factor w/ 1 level "Dusk Till Dawn.mp3": 1
```

str(training_set)

```
'data.frame':   1052 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Emot   : Factor w/ 8 levels "anger","contempt",..: 4 7 6 6 4 3 4 6 4 6 ...
 $ Pact   : Factor w/ 5 levels "Bicycling","Driving",..: 1 2 2 2 4 3 1 1 3 4 ...
 $ Mact   : Factor w/ 6 levels "browsing","chatting",..: 1 6 1 4 5 1 5 6 6 6 ...
 $ Session: Factor w/ 4 levels "afternoon","evening",..: 3 4 3 2 1 3 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ Song   : Factor w/ 101 levels "Aaj Ibaadat.mp3",..: 29 83 47 72 29 75 77 8 30 53 ...
```

Comment: Please show what `test_set` or `training_set` look like (e.g. `str()`). The error message is pretty clear, you probably misspelled something.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik added in question

Comment: Can you please use `str`? This doesn't tell us much about the variables (e.g. type).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik added

Comment: Hum, can't think of anything from the top of my head. If you provide a reproducible example I can try a few things, like specifying a model formula (`randomForest(Song ~ ., data = training_set)`) instead of passing on `x` and `y`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik i tried that too, doesn't work either! I am not able to understand what this post says either : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829674/r-random-forest-error-type-of-predictors-in-new-data-do-not-match?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: If the problem is only with a single-row dataset, then maybe someone somewhere has forgotten a `drop = FALSE` in a subsetting operation. What happens when you use `options(error=recover)`?

Comment: I tried drop and options recover gives 2 options predict() and predict.randomForest() for debug, doesn't help. I just tired leveling both sets using `levels(dataset$Emot) <- levels(training_set$Emot)`. It works but gives wrong and same output for every input:(.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik finally solved with weird solution. Thanks for your time n help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohk this worked successfully, weird solution. Equalized classes of training and test set. Following code binds the first row of training set to the test set and than delete it.

```
test_set <- rbind(training_set[1, ] , test_set)
test_set <- test_set[-1,]
```

done! it works for single input as well as single entry .csv file, without bringing error in model.