# "Subset" in R does not subset the way I want it to

Tags: r, subset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dropping factor levels in a subsetted data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/dropping-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame-in-r)

I am getting a little frustrated with R here, it would be great if anyone could help me with the following:I am trying to pull a subset out of my dataset but it does not work properly.

Specifics:
I have a spreadsheet with words and different features associated with each word
e.g. word   article  length ...
...
Now I am trying to look at individual words, e.g. pull out all instances where the word is "hairbrush". To do so, I tried:

```
hairbrush=subset(dataset, word=="hairbrush")
```

This seems to work fine and gives me the right dataset when I look at it with `fix` or `head`. However, as soon as I try to do things like `xtabs` or any kind of computation, I do not get very far because all the other words are still "there" and mess up my stats. E.g. when I do `levels`, it gives me "hairbrush", but also all other 200 words. All the data pertaining to these "hidden words" is `NA` but it still messes up my stats.

Is that the usual behavior of `subset`? Or am I doing something wrong? Or is this the wrong approach?

Oh, and in some similar questions on Google, people always asked for the output of `str`, so here it is:

```
> str(hairbrush)
'data.frame':   41 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ id       : Factor w/ 1352 levels "1-1-1-11-a.eaf",..: 210 240 267 295 320 351 378 403 427 452 ...
 $ speaker  : num  24 25 26 28 29 30 32 33 34 35 ...
 $ loc      : Factor w/ 2 levels "nb","xx": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ gilbertno: Factor w/ 27 levels "1","10","108",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ tword    : Factor w/ 65 levels "abaddream","afuneral",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ word     : Factor w/ 228 levels "abbe","aepfel",..: 164 93 99 93 92 100 94 94 28 93 ...
 $ loan     : Factor w/ 5 levels "FILE","maybe",..: 4 3 5 3 5 5 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ article  : Factor w/ 40 levels "a","das","dat",..: 34 34 33 33 34 34 34 34 13 34 ...
 $ gender   : Factor w/ 13 levels "a","af","amn",..: 11 11 7 7 11 11 11 11 7 11 ...
 $ comment  : Factor w/ 4 levels "0","die macht ja vorschlaege",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `droplevels` after subsetting to clean out unused levels.

Comment: thanks so much ben, that did the trick! can't believe that is not in my textbook...

Answer (score 3):

`subset` is working as intended. The problem you are having is due to `word` being a `factor`. When you subset the `data.frame`, `subset` doesn't redefine your variables, so `word` continues to carry with it all of the level information that was part of the original dataset. Try using `droplevels` to drop all of the unused levels from your `data.frame`.