# How can I drop unused levels from a data frame?

Tags: r, levels

Given the following mock data:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- data.frame(let = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = T), 
                num = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T))
y <- subset(x, let != 'a')
```

Creating a table of `y$let` yields

```
a  b  c  d  e 
0 20 21 22 18
```

But I don't want `a` to show anymore. If I try to do this:

```
levels(y$let) <- factor(y$let)
```

I mess the frequencies, since now `table(y$let)` gives me

```
b  d  c  e 
0 20 21 40
```

I'm aware I could do `xtabs(~ y$let, drop.unused.levels = T)` and work around the problem, but it doesn't reset the variable levels at its core (which is important to me, since this is an early change I'm making to the dataset which will carry on throughout the whole analysis). Moreover, `xtabs` is a different class from `table`, which will give me headaches later in the project.

The question is: how can I automatically change `levels(y$let)` so it doesn't show levels that were dropped when I created the subset? In this case, how can I make it show `[1] "b" "c" "d" "e"`?

Comment: The winning answer int he duplicate question is not as good as the answer here. The other should be marked as a duplicate of this since this is a MUCH better answer

Answer (score 140, accepted):

There's a recently added function in R for this:

```
y <- droplevels(y)
```

Answer (score 23):

Just do `y$let <- factor(y$let)`. Running `factor` on an existing factor variable will reset the levels to only those that are present.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Hong Ooi's answer, [here is](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-drop-factor-levels-in-a-dataset/) an example I found from R-Bloggers.

```
# Create some fake data
x <- as.factor(sample(head(colors()),100,replace=TRUE))
levels(x)
x <- x[x!="aliceblue"]
levels(x) # still the same levels
table(x) # even though one level has 0 entries!

The solution is simple: run factor() again:
x <- factor(x)
levels(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

The forcats package for working with factors is often a good choice.

```
library(forcats)
y$let <- fct_drop(y$let)
```