# R replaced values show up in table()

Tags: r, replace

Is there a way for replaced values not to show up in the table() function?

Problem is easily reproduceable
under R-Studio Version 0.98.1062, R version 3.1.1

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
y <- c("condition1", "condition2", "condition3", "condition1", "condition2", "condition3", "condition1", "condition2", "condition3", "condition1")
df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

Let's say I replace the name of "condition3" to "condition2"

```
df$y <- replace(df$y, df$y=="condition3","condition2")
table(df$y)
```

ouput =

condition1 condition2 condition3

4....................6......................0

Why does it print Condition3 in the table, when it has 0 values?
I would like a function that replaces condition3, so that it is not there, not just in the dataframe, but also in any further analysis. Is there a better way to replace values?

Comment: See `droplevels` perhaps?

Comment: See also a more general Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/dropping-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 2):

You can use `droplevels`, like this:

```
table(droplevels(df$y))
# 
# condition1 condition2 
#          4          6
```

Answer (score 0):

Also,to permanently remove "condition3" from the levels of df$y,

```
df$y <- factor(df$y)
```