# barplot: selecting data in R

Tags: r, selection, bar-chart

I have a problem for building barplot.

I am working on air traffic in different countries. I would like to get barplots for each countries with the different airport names in the X axis. The Y axis will show the quantity of airlines using the airport.

My plan is to make the script for 1 country and to replicate it manually for the others.

in my data, I have in the different columns:
Country / aiport / destination.
So each rows is actually one airline that is using the airport.

Do you have an idea about how to do this?

For now I have this idea:

```
UK<-traffic[traffic$Country=="UK",]

UK$airport <- as.factor(UK$airport)

countUK<-table(UK$airport)

barplot(countUK)
```

This is not working, I have a bunch of airports that are not in UK in the X axis...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example. [See here for how to do this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You could try to drop unused factor levels, i.e. `UK <- droplevels(UK)` after the line `UK$airport <- as.factor(UK$airport)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dropping factor levels in a subsetted data frame in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/dropping-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Answer found:

You could try to drop unused factor levels, i.e.

`UK <- droplevels(UK)` after the line `UK$airport <- as.factor(UK$airport)`.