# R subset function: why does it include non subsetted data?

Tags: r, subset

I am taking Datacamp's Data Analysis and Statistical Inference. The following is code to load related to the Global Index of Religiosity And Atheism and subsetting the US 2012 data.

```
load(url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/course/dasi/atheism.RData"))
us12 = subset(atheism, atheism$nationality == "United States" & atheism$year =="2012")
```

My question is why do I see the other countries when I type

```
table(us12)
```

Is there a way I can subset only the filtered data?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, when using the `subset` convenience function, you dont need to type `atheism$` inside it. Just access the variables directly, i.e. `subset(atheism, nationality == "United States" & year =="2012")`

Comment: When you subset the data frame the factor variables keep all the levels, so the problem is dropping unused factor levels after subsetting, which is [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/dropping-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame-in-r): `us12$nationality <- factor(us12$nationality)` and `us12$response <- factor(us12$response)` should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Because `us12` is a `data.frame` in which `nationality` and `response` columns are `factors`, including all the levels of the original `data.frame`.

In fact, `table(us12)` returns you the counts, and as you can see, all the counts for nationalities different from United States are zero.

If this is a problem for you, you can use the `droplevels` function, that removes the levels actually not present in the `data.frame`:

```
> us12dropped=droplevels(us12)
> table(us12dropped)
, , year = 2012

               response
nationality     atheist non-atheist
  United States      50         952
```

Comment: (+1) But you should add a hint to `droplevels`.

Comment: you can also do `table(us12,exclude=setdiff(levels(us12$nationality),"United States"))` but it's not as simple as using `droplevels`