# in R, recovering strings that have been converted to factors with factor()

Tags: r, categorical-data

I converted some columns from my dataset into factor levels to conduct analysis. How can I view the definitions of the factor levels which now inhabit my matrix? Are the original names lost? I used the following command on dtafactor, which is a matrix object.

```
dtafactor[,4:9]=factor(dtafactor[,4:9])
```

Comment: `levels(dtafactor[,4:9])`?

Comment: > levels(dtafactor[,5:9]).....

NULL

Comment: `str(dtafactor[,4:9])` results in what?

Comment: Is this what OP needs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/drop-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame?

Comment: What is the `class()` of the matrix (a matrix can only hold a single atomic type)? You can't (easily) store factors in a matrix. It would really help if you created a fully [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really have a matrix, the information is lost. The reason is that a matrix can't hold a mixture of variables and can't hold a factor variable. Thus the integers that are the basis of factors (together with the levels attribute) are coerced to a type that fits with the rest of the columns (and the levels are lost), probably to character.

```
mat <- matrix(letters[1:4], 2)
mat[,2] <- factor(mat[,2])
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "a"  "1" 
#[2,] "b"  "2"
```

You have to rerun your script up to that point. You probably should use a `data.frame` instead of a matrix as your data structure.