# How to plot Subset data without the unselected data in R

Tags: r, plot, subset

I want to plot a graph of this (see below), but after subsetting, R is plotting all variables, but only the data of the selected ones.

```
test<-subset(OrchardSprays,treatment == "A")
plot(test$treatment, test$decrease)
```

So is there a way to plot only the variable that I want without deleting it in my original data frame?

I don't want this!
[image]

Comment: `treatment` is a factor variable. If you make it a `character`, you'll have no further trouble, I reckon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `droplevels`:

```
test <- subset(OrchardSprays, treatment == "A")
test <- droplevels(test)
plot(test$treatment, test$decrease)
```

Comment: Super simple and nice! Thanks for this!

Comment: [Similar subject here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/drop-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test<-subset(OrchardSprays,treatment == "A")
test$treatment <- as.character(test$treatment)
plot(test$treatment, test$decrease)
```

I think the issue is that `test$treatment` is a factor with a bunch of levels, and that `plot` picks up on all of the levels when you plot the subset. By making `test$treatment` a string, you should avoid this issue.

Comment: You got a really good point here! But it says that there is a problem with as.character :

`Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

This works
   `test<-subset(OrchardSprays,treatment == "A")
    test$treatment <- as.factor(test$treatment)
    plot(test$treatment, test$decrease)`