# Extracted data frame selection still contains entries from full data frame set

Tags: r

I have a data frame (originally from a CSV file) with the columns NAME and YEAR. I have extracted a sample from this data frame of the first ten entries like so:

```
sample<-df(1:10,)
```

I want to know the frequency of the values in the NAME column so I input the following:

```
as.data.frame(table(sample$NAME))
```

This counts the frequency in the sample correctly but also includes every name from the original data frame in the 'Var1' column (all with a Freq of 0).

The same thing happens if I use unique(sample$NAME) as well: it lists the names from the sample along with all of the names from the original data frame as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a case of unused `level` in the 'NAME' `factor` column.  We can use `droplevels` or call `factor` again to remove those unused levels.

```
as.data.frame(table(droplevels(sample$NAME)))
```

Or

```
as.data.frame(table(factor(sample$NAME)))
```

Comment: Lots of thanks for this. I searched further on this subject and found this earlier SO q&a which goes into additional detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/drop-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame 

Specifically, sample<-droplevels(sample)

Comment: I tried to immediately, but it made me wait a few minutes. Thanks again.

Comment: @JdS Thanks, also consider to show some example dataset when you post in the future (for easier understanding).