# dplyr and length does not group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df%>%
    group_by(variable1)%>%
    summarise(length=length(levels(df$variable2))
```

group_by does not work and I have the same results for all the levels of the variable1.

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/drop-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to remove `df$`.  The `levels(df$variable2)` gets the `levels` in the full dataset. For `factor` variables, the unused levels remains unless we drop the levels with `droplevels`.

```
df %>%
   group_by(variable1)%>%
   summarise(length=length(levels(droplevels(variable2))))
```

Also, instead of using the `levels` route, we can use `n_distinct`

```
 df %>% 
   group_by(variable1) %>% 
   summarise(length=n_distinct(variable2))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(variable1=sample(letters[1:3], 
   10,replace=TRUE), variable2= sample(letters[1:5],10, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think the question was straightforward when we consider the general behavior of `levels` in a `factor`.