# Drop factor combinations in r boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a dataframe with a quantitatitve variable and two categorical variables with several factors each. When I make a boxplot graph with these I get a graph where the combinations of these factors with missing values appear empty. So, I want to drop these empty spaces in the graph.

I am using these formula:

```
boxplot(anova_propagacion$crecimiento ~ localidad*transgen, las=2)
```

and these is my data:

```
crecimiento transgen  localidad
1           19        N    YUCATAN
2            5        N    YUCATAN
3           17        N    YUCATAN
4           10        N    YUCATAN
5           10        N    YUCATAN
6            1        N    YUCATAN
7           19        N    NAYARIT
8            4        N    NAYARIT
9            7        N    NAYARIT
10          12        N    NAYARIT
11           2        N   PACIFICO
12          13        N    NAYARIT
13          19        N    NAYARIT
14           3        N        BCS
15           2        N        BCS
16           5        N        BCS
17           2        N        BCS
18           2        N        BCS
19           3        N        BCS
20          18        N   PACIFICO
21           2        N   PACIFICO
22           3        N   PACIFICO
23          17        N   PACIFICO
24           6        N   VERACRUZ
25           3        N   VERACRUZ
26           3        N   VERACRUZ
27          10        N   VERACRUZ
28           3        N        BCS
29           8        N        BCS
30           4        N     OAXACA
31           6        N     OAXACA
32           3        N        BCS
33         NaN        N    SINALOA
34         NaN        N TAMAULIPAS
35           5        N     OAXACA
36          17        Y     OAXACA
37          18        Y     OAXACA
38           3        Y TAMAULIPAS
39           6        Y TAMAULIPAS
40          19        Y    NAYARIT
41          19        Y    SINALOA
42           4        Y   PACIFICO
43          13        Y   PACIFICO
44           3        Y   PACIFICO
45          19        Y   PACIFICO
46          19        Y   PACIFICO
47          19        Y   PACIFICO
48          17        Y   VERACRUZ
49           2        Y        BCS
50          18        Y        BCS
51          19        Y        BCS
52         NaN        Y    YUCATAN
```

And i get this graph:

[image]

Please, can you help me to remove the empty spaces?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Have a look at the following SO page [Drop factor levels in a subsetted data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/drop-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame)

Comment: check `droplevels()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following gives a plot, where the gaps are omitted:

```
boxplot(crecimiento ~ interaction(localidad, transgen, drop = TRUE),
        data = na.omit(anova_propagacion), las = 2)
```

[image]

The two main changes compared to your code are:

- To calculate the interaction term in the formula I use `interaction(localidad, transgen, drop = TRUE)`. Setting `drop = TRUE` means that combinations that do not actually appear in the data are omitted.
- This alone is not enough, because certain combinations *do* appear in the data, but the value of `crecimento` is `NaN` (e.g., `SINALOA.N`). Therefore, they are not dropped, but there is still nothing to be plotted. This is solved by just removing those rows with `na.omit()`.

Comment: Thank you so so much Stibu :D, your answer was really helpful!