# Why are there extra levels listed in str(data) which aren't visible/accessible?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have merged two dataframes in R and when I check `str(data)`, it shows that some factors have hundreds of levels, even though when I check the dataframe it only contains 21 levels.

```
'data.frame':   21 obs. of  6 variables:
$ TrustName     : Factor w/ 382 levels "#NAME?","2Gether NHS Foundation Trust",..: 14 17 18 55 73 93 104 107 116 121 ...
$ TrustCode     : Factor w/ 317 levels " ","00D","00P",..: 134 86 122 205 154 241 194 152 208 306 ...
$ ResponseRate16: Factor w/ 70 levels "--","100","28",..: 18 21 17 23 8 31 35 13 30 17 ...
$ Base16        : Factor w/ 300 levels "--","1,039","1,057",..: 232 73 191 216 147 194 4 70 143 6 ...
$ ResponseRate15: Factor w/ 34 levels "27.29%","27.63%",..: 18 5 13 31 3 15 34 9 12 10 ...
$ Base15        : Factor w/ 34 levels "1,279","1,456",..: 23 7 18 12 31 19 28 6 15 32 ...
```

The factors with 300+ levels are the ones in question as they only contain between 20 and 30 values in total.

I even cleaned/removed the `#NAME?` values from the original dataframes before merging them and I checked that they had been removed successfully (they had).

why is this happening and how can I fix it to depict a more accurate picture?

Comment: Look at `droplevels` perhaps?

Comment: Just tried that and it still shows the same result.

Comment: What did you do exactly? Did you check `str(droplevels(data))` and it shows the same result?

Comment: And what do you mean with merged two dataframes? did the original dataframes already contain these factors with the high amounts of levels or were they added in the merging?

Comment: Not to worry, I have discovered that I need to apply `factor()` to the variable once I have merged the dataframes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1197154/636987