# Factors created when subsetting data frame

Tags: r

When using `subset` on a data frame, my resulting data frame has some odd behavior.
`df` is the subset of a larger data frame

```
>df

   buy_sell_count                 trt                 sector
1               1            0.023957              Apartment
2               1            0.026739           Strip Center
3               1  0.0705979999999999                   Mall
4               1  0.0595650000000001                 Office
5               1  0.0290539999999999             Industrial
```

I've tried the various drop-level practices shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/drop-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame) question, but none have worked.

When i do `mean(df$trt)` I get a   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
When i do `as.numeric(df$trt)` I get

```
 [1]  8  9 12 11 10  1  4  6  3  5  7  2
```

I think it has to do with the levels:
`df$trt` produces

```
 [1] 0.023957            0.026739            0.0705979999999999  0.0595650000000001  0.0290539999999999 
 [6] -0.01607            -0.188538           0.00279700000000016 -0.022502           0.00178300000000009
[11] 0.00770099999999996 -0.0191330000000001
12 Levels: -0.01607 -0.0191330000000001 -0.022502 -0.188538 0.00178300000000009 ... 0.0705979999999999
```

Comment: The problem isn't dropping levels, it's that your `trt` column shouldn't be a factor at all. Try `as.numeric(as.character())` on it, but really you should trace back upstream in your code to find out where it became a factor (e.g. when reading it in from file).

Comment: try `as.numeric(as.character(df$trt))`.  This should solve the issue at hand, but your bigger issue is happening either before or during subsetting

Comment: That worked. Thank you.