# Collapse, order and drop factors efficiently in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

Subsetting a large dataframe leaves us with a factor variable that needs reordering and dropping of missing factors. A reprex is below:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)

data <- c("10th Std. Pass", "11th Std. Pass", "12th Std. Pass", "5th Std. Pass", 
          "6th Std. Pass", "Diploma / certificate course", "Graduate", "No Education")

education <-  factor(sample(data, size = 5, replace = TRUE), 
                     levels = c(data, "Data not available"))

survey <-  tibble(education)
```

The code further below, [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/drop-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame), achieves what we want but we'd like to integrate the reordering and dropping of factors into our piped recoding of the survey.

```
recoded_s <- survey %>% mutate(education =
  fct_collapse(education,
"None" = "No Education",
"Primary" = c("5th Std. Pass", "6th Std. Pass"),
"Secondary" = c("10th Std. Pass", "11th Std. Pass", "12th Std. Pass"), 
"Tertiary" = c("Diploma / certificate course", "Graduate")
  ))

recoded_s$education
#> [1] Secondary Primary   Primary   Primary   Tertiary 
#> Levels: Secondary Primary Tertiary None Data not available


# Re-ordering and dropping variables
factor(recoded_s$education, levels = c("None", "Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary"))
#> [1] Secondary Primary   Primary   Primary   Tertiary 
#> Levels: None Primary Secondary Tertiary
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand. Could you elaborate why wrapping everything inside a `mutate` call doesn't suffice?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)
survey %>%
    mutate(
        education = fct_collapse(
            education,
            "None" = "No Education",
            "Primary" = c("5th Std. Pass", "6th Std. Pass"),
            "Secondary" = c("10th Std. Pass", "11th Std. Pass", "12th Std. Pass"),
            "Tertiary" = c("Diploma / certificate course", "Graduate")),
        education = factor(education, levels = c("None", "Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary")))
```

---

### Alternative using `dplyr::recode`

```
lvls <- list(
    "No Education" = "None",
    "5th Std. Pass" = "Primary",
    "6th Std. Pass" = "Primary",
    "10th Std. Pass" = "Secondary",
    "11th Std. Pass" = "Secondary",
    "12th Std. Pass" = "Secondary",
    "Diploma / certificate course" = "Tertiary",
    "Graduate" = "Tertiary")
survey %>%
    mutate(
        education = factor(recode(education, !!!lvls), unique(map_chr(lvls, 1))))
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I genuinely didn't realise I could just plug it in... At the same time, I was hoping for something more succinct either in forcats or elsewhere that would allow for those actions to be carried out simultaneously; it seems like a fairly common thing to want to do?

Comment: @FonsMA I've added an alternative approach using `dplyr::recode` which requires a `list` of the old to new factor level mappings. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks Maurits, I reckon your first answer is actually better

Comment: @FonsMA No worries:-) I think I prefer the second approach, as it can be written in a single `mutate` line with a `list` defining the old/new `factor` levels. This seems slightly more generalisable and robust, because we're not explicitly hard-coding `factor` levels twice (once within `fct_collapse` and once within `factor`). Anyway, perhaps there will be a better answer.

Comment: I agree nothing looks particularly nice... :D For your second solution, it may again be my ignorance, not sure I know what the `unique(map_chr(lvls,1))` is doing there.. so let's see if people in other regions know what they're doing. I'm knocking off!

Comment: @FonsMA For what it's worth: `unique(map_chr(lvls, 1)` sets the `factor` levels to the unique `character` entries of the vector of `list` entries.